# Grails: Change contents of message.properties (i18n) in production

Tags: grails, internationalization, properties-file

Is is possible to modify text in message.properties when in production without a redeploy/restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible if you use the default `messageSource` bean. If you want to do this, one option is to store the messages in the database rather than properties files. Here are a couple of plugins that support this (I've never used either of them myself)

- http://grails.org/plugin/localizations
- https://github.com/goeh/grails-i18n-db

Alternatively, replace the default `messageSource` bean with one that supports reloading, e.g. `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possible, but you need to replace the default messageSource bean with a `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`. You can do this by configuring a new messageSource bean definition in your grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy as follows:

```
beans = {
      messageSource(org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource) {
        basenames = ["classpath:grails-app/i18n/myApp", "file:grails-app/i18n/messages", "WEB-INF/grails-app/i18n/messages"]
    }
}
```

The above will work in both development and production. You may also want to research other options available to you using the [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html).

Comment: Will this allow you to put the resource bundle outside the WAR file?

Comment: Sure. You can include it in the basenames.

Comment: Do you think this is preferable to the database approach? One advantage of the database approach is that you could atomically update the messages, but I don't know how you'd do this reliably if you're storing them in files.

Comment: I'd agree that using the database is a more common approach. Still, using files on the file system does have value. In the sense of micro services, or where the message sources are maintained and produced though an external system/process. I have seen that a few times. Typically though those are the exceptions to the case. Most people would just stuff the data into a database and be done with it.

Comment: I should also note that the location can be any valid URI (even an external micro service via URL).